# Codeigniter 4 ignoring model insert callback

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

Running model->insert() from my controller does not trigger the beforeInsert function, below is my model and the function from my conntroller

```
    <?php

namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class UserModel extends Model {
    
    protected $table            = 'admin_users';
    protected $useAutoIncrement = true;
    protected $primaryKey       = 'row_uid';
    protected $returnType       = 'object';
    protected $beforeInsert     = ['passwordHash'];
    protected $allowCallbacks   = true;
    protected $allowedFields    = ['id', 'row_uid', 'username', 'email', 'password', 'active', 'deleted_at'];
    
    public function __construct() {
        return $this;
    }
    
    protected function passwordHash($data) {
        $data['data']['row_uid'] = uniqid('',true);
        $data['data']['password'] = password_hash($data['data']['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        if(isset($data['data']['password_c'])) unset($data['data']['password_c']);
        return $data;
    }

    
}
```

And here is the controller function

```
public function postRegister() {
    $request = \Config\Services::request();
    if($post = $request->getPost()) {
        $valid = $this->validate([
            'username'    => 'is_unique[admin_users.username]', // Change table name to be dynamic
            'email'    => 'required|valid_email|is_unique[admin_users.email]', // Change table name to be dynamic
            'password' => 'required|min_length[10]|max_length[100]',
            'password_c' => 'required|matches[password]',
        ]);
        if(!$valid) {
            $this->data['errors'] = $this->validator->getErrors();
            foreach($post as $key => $e) {
                if(isset($this->data['errors'][$key])) {
                    $this->data['invalid_fields'][$key] = ' is-invalid';
                } else $this->data['invalid_fields'][$key] = '';
            }
            return $this->getRegister();
        }
        $l = $this->userModel->insert($post);
        echo '<pre>',var_dump($l),'</pre>';exit;
    }
}
```

I determine that the callback is not running because the password is not hashed, the uid is not generated and running die or exit does nothing.

Thank you

EDIT:

I got it working by adding allowCallback() but i shouldn't need this?

```
$this->userModel->allowCallbacks(true)->insert($post);
```

Answer (score 0):

1 - Delete the constructor method in the model; you don't need that .

2- set `protected $allowCallbacks = true;` before `$beforeInsert = ['passwordHash'];`

The above approach is standard coding in the Codeigniter framework. If those steps didnt resolve the problem, the solution is to check the database for the `row_uid` and `password` types.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, to be honest it just works so i left it. i removed the return $this from the constructor, not sure what it was doing there, and i have a feeling that if i had parent::__construct(); it would have worked, but it's not tested.